# How to re-arrange a list based on a set of steps?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to re-arrange a list based on these steps:

1. First move every operator (+,-,*) 1 index to the left by switching it with the element to the left.
2. Then find any '+' or '-' two indexes ahead of a *, and move the '+' or '-' to the index before the *.

**Example**

["a","-","2","*","b","+","c"]

["-","a","*","2","+","b","c"]

["-","a","+","*","2","b","c"]

I have an imperative programming background, so my initial idea was to have an iterator as an argument, and keep track of the position in the index like that, but I could not get it to work. My second idea was to embrace Haskell and use list comprehension with generators, but I struggled there as well. Any ideas or solutions are appreciated!

Comment: You can use *explicit recursion*.

Comment: Are you trying to write an infix-to-prefix converter? You are probably better off building an AST, then doing a pre-order traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of *explicit recursion*. You can for example move elements one position to the left with:

```
isOperator :: String -> Bool
isOperator "+" = True
isOperator "-" = True
isOperator "*" = True
isOperator _ = False

stepOne :: [String] -> [String]
stepOne (x:xs@(o:xs'))
    | isOperator o = o : x : stepOne xs'
    | otherwise = x : stepOne xs
stepOne xa@[_] = xa
stepOne [] = []
```

Here the `(x:xs@(o:xs'))` pattern matches with lists with two or more elements. THe first element is `x`, the second is `o`, the remaining elements is stored in the `xs'` variable. `xs` is the tail of the "outer" cons. We check if `o` is an operator, if that is the case we swap with `x` and recurse on the tail `xs'`. If `o` is not an operator, we recurse on the tail `xs'`.

For the given sample data, we get:

```
Prelude> stepOne ["a","-","2","*","b","+","c"]
["-","a","*","2","+","b","c"]
```

I leave step two as an exercise.

That being said, one of the success stories of Haskell is probably parsing. Several libraries and tools exist like [**`parsec`** [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) and [**`attoparsec`** [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec). [**`happy`** [haskell.org]](https://www.haskell.org/happy/) is a *compiler compiler* that can construct a parser in Haskell based on a grammer. You thus do not *per se* need to perform infix-to-prefix conversion, but let tools do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks! The libraries could definitely be useful for a proper project, but I'm mostly interested in learning about list manipulation in functional programming through simple examples I can understand.